# Checking neighboring diagonal positions in 2D Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 2D array setup to store game-pieces in a checker board, and I have create methods that allow me to check to see if the piece at the selected location can make a jump. Each method works on its own, but when I try to use them together --specifically the one that checks southwest direction--I get `Access violation reading location` error. I haven't yet figure out how to check if I am going out of bounds, but I don't think that is the issue here. `row` and `col` are the `height` and `width` of the array and `r` and `c` are the coordinates entered by the user.

```
if (jumpPosRightToLeft(board, 'X', 'O', row, col, r,c) ||
    jumpPosRightToLeft(board, 'O', 'X', row, col, r,c)) {
    cout << "can make move";
}

if (jumpPosLeftToRight(board, 'X', 'O', row, col, r, c) ||
    jumpPosLeftToRight(board, 'X', 'O', row, col, r, c)) {
    cout << "can make move";
}
```

And here is how the methods are implemented:

```
bool jumpPosRightToLeft(char **board, char x, char y, int row, int col) {
    if (board[row][col] == x &&
        board[row - 1][col + 1] == y &&
        board[row - 2][col + 2] == ' ') {

        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }

bool jumpPosLeftToRight(char **board, char x, char y, int row, int col) {
    if (board[row][col] == x &&
        board[row + 1][col - 1] == y &&
        board[row + 2][col - 2] == ' ') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are, indeed, going out-of-bounds.

What you should do is something like this:

```
#define BOARDSIZE 8 // Define whatever board size (square) you want here

bool jumpPosLeftToRight(char **board, char tokenA, char tokenB, int r, int c, int row, int col) {
    if (row + 1 >= BOARDSIZE || row + 2 >= BOARDSIZE || col - 1 < 0 || col - 2 < 0) return false;

    if (board[row][col] == tokenA &&
        board[row + 1][col - 1] == tokenB &&
        board[row + 2][col - 2] == ' ') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm certain you can extrapolate it to your other functions easily enough. When working with stuff like arrays, you should ***always*** bounds-check before attempting to operate on them.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about #define BOARDSIZE, so I can really just set that to any size even it it's not my real boardsize? Right now, my boardsize dimensions are coming in from the user.

Comment: Then make your functions take another argument that specifies the board size. What I did up there is a simple macro that defines a constant board size.

Comment: Ah. Okay. I am still getting the same errors when I try to use the diagonal functions in separate if statements as shown above. So if I try to find northeast diagonal it works, but when I try to check southeast my program crashes with  Access violation exception.

Comment: You need to do _proper_ bounds-checking in your functions. For every board location you're checking, make sure it's in bounds (either below the board size or greater than or equal to zero).

Comment: In the code snippet you pasted, you're not checking the right bounds. If you're incrementing, you should be checking against your maximum size. If you're decrementing (going down), you should be checking against 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122355/discussion-between-mahmud-adam-and-sebastian-lenartowicz).